# consultar, tablas Mysql y sumar unas columnas de una de las tablas

Tags: mysql

Tengo tres tablas propietarios, departamentos y deudores, de la tabla deudores, necesito sumar los campos, interes, multas y gasto_comun, en una nueva columna que se llama deuda, de la tabla deudores todas sus columnas y de propietarios nombre y apellidos, para ello tengo el siguiente SELECT:

```
SELECT SUM(interes+multas+gasto_comun) as deuda, d.*, 
        p.id_propietario, p.nombre, p.apellidos, 
        dp.id_depto, dp.nro_depto
        FROM deudores d
        INNER JOIN propietarios p ON d.id_propietario = p.id_propietario
        INNER JOIN deptos dp ON d.id_depto = dp.id_depto
```

Tengo 2 registros, pero la consulta solo muestra uno, me pueden ayudar por favor.

Comment: Si te muestra uno en lugar de dos registros ¿por qué no utilizás `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Gracias, eso era, ahora ya funciona como la necesito